# PhoneGap Online and offline mode

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I new to phone gap and have build an android app with command line interface (CLI) but when the function loads to alert me if the phone is online or off line it fails. Below are the codes and details of how i installed the modules.

My issue is the last alert I get is "OK58" then the phone just keeps loading and loading.

Javascript code

function onDeviceReady() 
{

```
"use strict";
alert("ok55");
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

alert("ok58");


//try{
    var networkState = navigator.connection &&    navigator.connection.type;
```

//      setTimeout(function(){
            networkState = navigator.connection && navigator.connection.type;

```
        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

        alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
    //}, 500);
  // }catch(e){
  //    alert(e);
 //   $.each(navigator, function(key, value){
  //      alert(key+' => '+value);
//    });
// }

 alert("hello");
```

My html header. the above code is contained in common.js

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src   *; style-src *  'unsafe-inline'; script-src *  'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Eurotech</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_signiture.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css"/> 
    <script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/phonegap-nfc-0.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/nfc.js"></script>
    <script src="js/common.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ajaxmanager.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqm.page.params.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/task.js"></script>

    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.34982.js"></script>
    <script src="js/application.js"></script>
    <script src="js/signatureCapture.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
```

In my config.xml file i have the below contents included

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" spec="0.2.15" source="pgb" />
<plugin name="NfcPlugin" value="com.chariotsolutions.nfc.plugin.NfcPlugin"/>
```

And

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.15" />
```

I installed plugins via the command line using

```
phonegap  plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

I think thats everything. How can i debug this better? Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some typo in your code, this should work (untested):

```
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
```

All device request are event driven. So it makes no sense to put them in a timeout.

Please read the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-network-information.

For debugging install https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-console then you can watch the output in your SDK and/or in your browser developer info. Use Safari for iOS and Chrome for Android.

If you have an old Android you can also use weinre for debugging: https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/

**Update:**

Here you have a working example, tested on iPad 9.2.

```
var app = {
    initialize: function () {

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", app.onDeviceReady, false);
        document.addEventListener("online", app.onOnline, false);
        document.addEventListener("offline", app.onOffline, false);

    }, onDeviceReady: function () {

        alert("App is started");

        app.getNetworkState();

    }, getNetworkState: function () {

        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN] = "Unknown connection";
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = "Ethernet connection";
        states[Connection.WIFI] = "WiFi connection";
        states[Connection.CELL_2G] = "Cell 2G connection";
        states[Connection.CELL_3G] = "Cell 3G connection";
        states[Connection.CELL_4G] = "Cell 4G connection";
        states[Connection.NONE] = "No network connection";

        alert("Connection type: " + states[networkState]);

    }, onOnline: function(){

        alert("Device is online");

        app.getNetworkState();

    }, onOffline: function(){

        alert("Device is offline");

    }
};

app.initialize();
```

If this is not working, then you have a problem with your cordova /plugin installation. Good luck. ;-))

Comment: Your changes did make the screen stop going white but i never get the but i still get the page keep loading. I am going to try your debugging tips. Thank you

Comment: You have two event listener in your code: online and offline. Are the function onOnline and onOffline in your code? Otherwise you will get an error. And you should put the event listener outside of the device ready event.

Comment: var networkState = navigator.connection.type; it will not go past this point. I assume the plugin is not configured properly??

Comment: Whatever i try the network plugin does not seem to call

Comment: Ok, i think i have a problem then with my cordova /plugin installation i got "app is started"

Comment: ps with your revision that app do longer keeps looping but i get no notification online or off line